# Extract calendar events from .ics link into a calendar on my website

Tags: php, html, calendar, icalendar

I'm building a simple website for school and would like to implement my class schedule on the website. I currently have access to the schedule via a continuously updating .ics link. I would like to extract one event at a time and place it on my website.

Is there a simple javascript or jquery that does this? Or how would I go about extracting events from a .ics file in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this Parser can convert your .ics File into well readen html:

[ICS Parser](https://packagist.org/packages/johngrogg/ics-parser)

[If you just want to convert to text](https://icalendar.org/validator.html)

[For Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-ics-importer/)

Hope I can help!

P.S.: If you want an example post your .ics File (Code || Link)